# insert "\r" into mysql db without escaping to "\\r" - codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, textarea

I have a `textarea` and am submitting the form it is in using AJAX using GET. 
I want to preserve the whitespace, so i have a url that look a bit like

```
http://.../notes/insert/?user_id=12&note_string=new /r/r/r/r/r/rline&account_id=
```

however when i use `$this->db->insert();` 
it converts the query to

```
INSERT INTO `notes` (`user_id`, `note_string`, `account_id`)
VALUES ('12', 'new \\r\\r\\r\\r\\r\\rline', '')
```

(in the controller i then replace `/r` for `\r`)

Is there a way of escaping the escape? lol or just letting the `\r` through?

Thank you

Comment: if you want to preserver line breaks when displaying the output from the db, use the php nl2br function...

Comment: The problem is getting the line breaks recorded in the db in the first place

Comment: that does the same thing and stores the `\n` as a string rather than an actual line break because codeigniter escapes it by inserting `\\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at 'Query Bindings' in the CodeIgniter documentation http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```